# Circular dependency in a simple, 3-file project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This issue have been coming up frequently in a previous project and I've been avoiding it by keeping the definitions of methods inside the same header file as the declarations of said methods, despite knowing how bad of a practice that is, but now I'm trying to setup a project template and I want to do this correctly, here's what I have:

**Window.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

// Two objects
sf::RenderWindow w(sf::VideoMode(690, 500), "Hello World");
sf::Event e;

class window_methods {
public:
    void close_window(); // Declaration of a method that manipulates the two objects
};

window_methods mw; // And object created from the class containing the method
```

**Window.cpp**

```
#include "Window.h"

void window_methods::close_window() {
    // Definition of the function that manipulates 'e' and 'w'
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Window.h"

int main() {
    while (w.isOpen()) {
        mw.close_window(); // Object method is called
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "class window_methods mw" (?mw@@3Vwindow_methods@@A) already defined in Main.obj    SFML Project    D:\Projects\Other\Libraries\SFML Template 5.0\SFML Project\SFML Project\Window.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "class sf::Event e" (?e@@3VEvent@sf@@A) already defined in Main.obj SFML Project    D:\Projects\Other\Libraries\SFML Template 5.0\SFML Project\SFML Project\Window.obj  1   
Error   LNK2005 "class sf::RenderWindow w" (?w@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in Main.obj   SFML Project    D:\Projects\Other\Libraries\SFML Template 5.0\SFML Project\SFML Project\Window.obj  1   
Error   LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found  SFML Project    D:\Projects\Other\Libraries\SFML Template 5.0\SFML Project\Debug\SFML Project.exe   1
```

This problem only started appearing when I started working with SFML, and like I said, I've been avoiding it by including declarations and definitions in the same file, but I know why that's a bad practice, and I want to know how to stop doing it, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answers below explain how to solve the problem. But please think about why you have the problem in the first place: You have global variables. Do you really want to keep them? There can be good reasons to have global variables, but in many cases they are a short cut that create more problems that they solve. So why not put all these variables in a `Renderer` class and add the `window_methods` to that class? Then, the user can just use that `Renderer`. Or several of them.

Comment: This is not a circular dependency problem. It's just a regular 'right way to declare and define global variables' problem. Something that catches a lot of newbies out.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Understood, I've been encountering this problem but on a much bigger scale (We're talking dozens of objects instead of 3) and for some reason putting everything inside one giant class didn't cross my mind, I'll start applying this method from now on, thank you!

Comment: @john Honestly before reading the answers here I didn't even know declaring and defining variables were two separate things, but I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `Window.h` use

```
extern sf::RenderWindow w;
extern sf::Event e;
extern window_methods mw;
```

in `Window.cpp` use

```
sf::RenderWindow w(sf::VideoMode(690, 500), "Hello World");
sf::Event e;
window_methods mw;
```

**Defining** these three variables in the header file makes them exist
in every translation unit (compiled .cpp leading to a .obj) that includes it.

You have to **declare** them with `extern` in the header file so that
everyone including this header file can know these variables exist *somewhere*, but only **define** them once in
a single translation unit.

The linker will make sure that these variables that are referenced from
many translation units (.obj file) actually exist and only once in
the whole set of .obj files.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not circular dependency (compilation problem), but multiple definition of variables in different translation units (linker problem).

You've got two translation units: main.cpp and Window.cpp.

Each .cpp file includes Window.h. So your variables declared in Window.h appear in each translation unit after compilation. Then the linker sees duplicates and complains.

The usual way is to define variable in the header file with **extern** keyword and declare it in the source.

The other option available since C++17 is to make them **inline**. The advantage is that you can use only header without a source and that variables are located only in one place. The disadvantage is that it makes using global variables easier which is generally considered to be an anti-pattern.

```
// Window.h
inline sf::RenderWindow w(sf::VideoMode(690, 500), "Hello World");
inline sf::Event e;
inline window_methods mw;
```

Comment: I'll probably either be using *extern* like you and another answer told me, or avoid using global variable entirely, like one of the comments told me, but I'll keep the *inline* method in mind, thank you.